# Quadratic approximation of function of two variables near critical point

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, optimization

I know that to second-order, the Taylor polynomial of a function $f(x,y)$ at a critical point $(a,b)$ which gives a negative minimum is
$$f(x,y)\sim f(a,b)+c_1(x-a)^2+c_2(y-b)^2+c_3(x-a)(y-b)$$
for $c_1=f_{xx}(a,b)/2>0$, $c_2=f_{yy}(a,b)/2>0$ and $c_3=f_{xy}(a,b)$.
Clearly then, for $\epsilon>0$ arbitrarily small and $0\leq|(x-a,y-b)|\leq\epsilon$, the graph of $f$ should look like an elliptic paraboloid opening upwards, which has equation
$$z=\frac{(x-x_1)^2}{\alpha^2}+\frac{(y-y_1)^2}{\beta^2}.$$
I am trying to use the Taylor approximation above to show that near $(a,b)$,
$$f(x,y)\sim f(a,b)+C((x-a)^2+(y-b)^2)$$
for some positive constant $C$. I know how to get 
$$f(x,y)\geq f(a,b)+C((x-a)^2+(y-b)^2),$$
but was wondering if the other is true. Warning: I don't even know if it is possible! But it seems perfectly reasonable, since if it was to hold, the it would imply that 
$$f(x,y)-f(a,b)\sim C((x-a)^2+(y-b)^2),$$
which is true since $f(a,b)$ is a minimum and $C((x-a)^2+(y-b)^2)\geq0$. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$c_1(x-a)^2+c_2(y-b)^2+c_3(x-a)(y-b)$ is the quadratic form associated to $Hess(f)$ and you cannot remove the third term. If $f$ has a local minimum in $(a,b)$, then $c_1\geq 0,c_2\geq 0,c_1c_2-c_3^2\geq 0$; conversely if $c_1> 0,c_2> 0,c_1c_2-c_3^2>0$, then $f$ has a local minimum in $(a,b)$.